# Do I need to encode numerical variables like "year"?

Tags: dataset, normalization, feature-scaling, encoding

I have a simple time-series dataset. it has a date-time feature column.

```
user,amount,date,job
chris, 9500, 05/19/2022, clean
chris, 14600, 05/12/2021, clean
chris, 67900, 03/27/2021, cooking
chris, 495900, 04/25/2021, fixing
```

Using Pandas, I split this column into multiple features like `year, month, day`.

```
## Convert Date Coloumn into Date Time type
data["date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["date"], errors="coerce")

## Order by User and Date
data = data.sort_values(by=["user", "date"])

## Split Date into Year, Month, Day
data["year"] = data["date"].dt.year
data["month"] = data["date"].dt.month
data["day"] = data["date"].dt.day
```

I applied feature_engine's CyclicalTransformer on `month, day` features leaving `year` feature alone.

```
data = CyclicalTransformer(variables=["month", "day"], drop_original=True).fit_transform(data)
```

Now, I'm unsure what to do with `year` feature. I was thinking of applying MinMaxScaler on it, but I wonder whether I could leave it as it is since it is numerical already.

Comment: what is going to go into the input of your time series model?  Is is only year, or month,day,year?  If you are doing time series analysis you usually have to convert a date to a datetime.

Comment: it's month, day, year.